# I just installed webmin on a Centos 8 machine and when I try to connect to localhost:10000 I get a timeout

Tags: timeout, webmin, centos8

I just installed webmin on a Centos 8 machine and when I try to connect to localhost:10000 I get a timeout.

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: For future reference, please include any troubleshooting steps you took, as well as any details, like what command you used to install the webmin package, where you got it from (just yum install, GUI installer, or download RPM off the Webmin website - provide exact link).

Comment: Provided that the service is listening (`ss -l sport 10000`), can you add some log file entries (look into `/var/log`)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check to see if the service is running. If the webmin service is not running, you will not be able to access it. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-check-the-status-of-a-service-using-systemd/
2. Check the list of open ports on your system. Something like `sudo netstat -anopt` will list all open TCP ports (look for lines that contain LISTEN and 10000). This will tell you if Webmin is actually listening on port 10000. More details on **netstat** here: https://www.tecmint.com/find-open-ports-in-linux/
3. Webmin defaults to HTTPS in some cases. Try both http://localhost:10000/ and https://localhost:10000/
4. Finally make sure that Webmin listens on localhost and not your actual IP. For example, if the computer in question has an IP of 192.168.1.10, then http://192.168.1.10:10000/ may work, but http://localhost:10000/ may not, if Webmin is not set up to listen on localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: hi thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, firewalld could block the access to the port, then:

- `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=10000/tcp`
- `firewall-cmd --reload`